# Stuck while installing Netgen on QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, ubuntu

I'm compiling Netgen in QT (Ubuntu) and I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to show the Netgen GUI.

When I run `netgen` from my terminal, the message below shows up in the terminal and the Netgen User Interface appears:

[image: When I run Netgen from my Terminal]

But, when I run my project from QT, the same thing shows up in the terminal, but without the GUI:

[image: When I run Netgen from my QT]

What do I need to do to get the Netgen GUI in the second scenario?